# How do I resolve RNScreensPackage error while building in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  103 actionable tasks: 75 executed, 28 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

  Note: /Users/temp/kotlinProject/weve_client/node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativedocumentpicker/RNDocumentPickerModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
                                                Note: /Users/temp/kotlinProject/weve_client/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/src/oldarch/java/com/oblador/vectoricons/VectorIconsModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  /Users/temp/kotlinProject/weve_client/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: package com.swmansion.rnscreens
/Users/temp/kotlinProject/weve_client/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
new RNScreensPackage()
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: class PackageList
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

                                                        * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 17s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

An error occurs with the above content, so I can't run it. I've tried removing the module folder, cleaning Gradle, etc., but the error still occurs. What part is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant comment since i don't have enough reputation, but in my case using OpenJDK20 had a lot of problems with compiling some libraries such as `react-native-screens` and `react-native-safe-area-context`. Downgrading to OpenJDK 17 fixed all the errors (and as well using it's compatible gradle version, 7.3).